# Google appscript append CSVs into one Master CSV

Tags: google-apps-script

Im able to append multiple CSVs in a folder into one CSV with many tabs. But I get hung up on the second to last line, "Getting the range".

```
function mergeSheets() {
  /* Retrieve the desired folder */
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("CSVfolder").next();  
  /* Get all spreadsheets that resided on that folder */
  var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFilesByType("text/csv");
  if (spreadSheets.hasNext()) {
    /* Create the new spreadsheet that you store other sheets */
    var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Merged Sheets");
    /* Iterate over the spreadsheets over the folder */
    while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) {
      var sheet = spreadSheets.next();
      /* Load the csv data */
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(sheet.getBlob().getDataAsString(), ",");
      /* Copy the sheet to the new merged Spread Sheet */
      var newSheet = newSpreadSheet.insertSheet("import_"+sheet.getName());
      for (var i=0;i<csvData.length;i++) {
        newSheet.appendRow(csvData[i]);
      }
    } 
  }   
}

function combineArrays() {

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const arrayData = [];
const sheets = ss.getSheets();

 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     const sh = sheets[i];
     const sourceValues = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
    arrayData.push(...sourceValues);
    Logger.log(arrayData);
 }

ss.getSheetByName("Target Sheet").getRange(19, 19, arrayData.length, arrayData[0].length).setValues(arrayData);
 }
```

How do you add multiple CSVs from a folder, which row counts may vary, into one single sheet. Not separate tabs?  I don't have much experience in Javascript.

Thank you for your time and your help.

Comment: "sh.getLastRow()?"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you asking but maybe this will help.

```
function mergeSheets() {
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("CSVfolder").next();
  var csvs = myFolder.getFilesByType("text/csv");
  if (csvs.hasNext()) {
    var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Merged Sheets");
    while (csvs.hasNext()) {
      var sh = csvs.next();
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(sh.getBlob().getDataAsString(), ",");
      var nsh = newSpreadSheet.insertSheet("import_" + sh.getName());
      nsh.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From `But I get hung up on the second to last line, "Getting the range".` and `How do you add multiple CSVs from a folder, which row counts may vary, into one single sheet. Not separate tabs?`, I guessed that your current issue is at `ss.getSheetByName("Target Sheet").getRange(19, 19, arrayData.length, arrayData[0].length).setValues(arrayData);`. If my understanding is correct, I guess that the reason for your current issue might be due to the different number of columns for each sheet. In order to modify this, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this case, your `combineArrays` is modified as follows.

```js
function combineArrays() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const arrayData = [];
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const sh = sheets[i];
    const sourceValues = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
    arrayData.push(...sourceValues);
  }

  // I added and modified the below script. Ref: https://github.com/tanaikech/UtlApp
  const maxLen = Math.max(...arrayData.map((r) => r.length));
  const values = arrayData.map((r) => [...r, ...Array(maxLen - r.length).fill(null)]);
  ss.getSheetByName("Target Sheet").getRange(19, 19, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- By this modification, the values of `values` are put from "S19" of "Target Sheet".